# Unable to manage internal and extrenal records in Powerdns

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Previously I had Bind9 in my production environment. To get rid of manual record add-in primary and secondary DNS servers, I implemented Master and Slaver replication using PowerDNS via poweradmin web-based panel.

Now I can add records of my domain via the web interface of poweradmin, which are replicated on both ns1 & ns2. But I didn't get any way to manage the Internal and External records in PowerDNS.
Is anyone who can guide me to achieve internal and external records management in PowerDNS?

Comment: How were you doing it in Bind9? (And why weren't you using automatic replication in Bind9?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What actually I need is the:
Let's assume there is our mail service on the subdomain mail.example.com with IP 192.168.10.X and it's mapped to a public IP. All I need is If someone hit mail.example.com on the browser via the internal network the traffic should go via 192.168.10.X but if someone hit mail.example.com via the external network it should go via public IP Address.